# Asymptotic expansion of $u_n$ such that $u_n^n-u_n-n=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, asymptotics

One can show that that the function $f_n : x \mapsto x^n-x-n$ admits a unique root (if $x\ge 1$). Then, we define $u_n\in [1,+\infty)$ such that $u_n^n-u_n-n=0$. I can prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to +\infty} u_n =1$. Then I set $u_n=1+\epsilon_n$ (with $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to +\infty} \epsilon_n =0$) and I've tried to find an equivalent of $\epsilon_n$ (when $n \to +\infty$) as follows
$$ (1+\epsilon_n)^n = 1+\epsilon_n+n \qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad n \ln(1+\epsilon_n)=\ln(n+1+\epsilon_n)$$
Now since $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to +\infty} \epsilon_n =0$, I know that $n \ln(1+\epsilon_n) \underset{n\to +\infty}{\sim} n\epsilon_n$ and $\ln(n+1+\epsilon_n)\underset{n\to +\infty}{\sim} \ln(n)$ which gives me
$$ \epsilon_n \underset{n\to +\infty}{\sim} \frac{\ln(n)}{n}$$
But "numerically", it seems wrong. Where is my mistake?

Comment: "But "numerically", it seems wrong. Where is my mistake?" No mistake, please show the numerics you got.

Comment: out of interest, how did you prove that $ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} u_n=1$?

Comment: a .. i got it set $u_n =n^{1/n}v_n$ and we get an easy app of the method of detailed balance (and by the way also the higher correction i obtain from there match your result,well done and +1)

Comment: Could I know the source or book of the problem? This kind of problem is really interesting to me and I would like to learn more about it.

Comment: @user635988 This problem was an oral exam for a French engineer school.

Comment: @user37238 actually i am also preparing for the cycle ingénieur next year. So yeah, where did you get it? I only able to find some written exam

Comment: @user635988 If you read French, there are a lot of books only about math oral exams (try keywords Centrale, Mines or Polytechnique oral math).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good to me! I find the same result, and numerical agreement. Here's a plot of the ratio of the solution to your approximation, $\epsilon_n / (\ln n/n)$:

[image: Ratio to asymptote]

This is indeed tending fairly rapidly to $1$.

---

The next corrections to the equation are $-n \epsilon^2/2 \sim (\ln n)^2/n$ on the LHS and $1/n$ on the RHS. Thus the LHS correction is larger. So let's solve
$n \epsilon - n \epsilon^2/2 \sim \ln n$. This gives the next correction:
$$\epsilon_n \sim \frac{\ln n}{n} + \frac{(\ln n)^2}{2n^2} + \cdots$$
This indeed matches with the error too, if we plot $(\epsilon_n - \ln n/n)/((\ln n)^2/2n^2)$:

[image: Next asymptotic term]